# Are there Unit Tests for mvcMusicStore?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

The reference app distributed with MVC3 RTM is a great learning tool in that it shows a comprehensive application. but what app (these days) exist without Unit Tests? It doesn't seem possible that the team who poured so much work into providing such a beast wouldn't have employed Unit Tests as they built it. Why not make that work public?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not that's how it is. Not a single unit test :-)